# DPDK VLAN strip code using memcpy results in data corruption

Tags: memcpy, dpdk

The VLAN strip code for egress GTP packets results in source IP address ac150569 getting corrupted. After VLAN tag(4 bytes) is removed the source IP in the packet becomes ac150000 which is wrong.

Packet dump before VLAN tag is removed:

```
0ca402e8 deb15254 00b3fb19 81000873 08004500 002a00fc 00003e11 bf42ac15 05690a5f 00aa0868 08680016 001c3202 000600
```

Code for VLAN strip:

```
memcpy((rte_pktmbuf_mtod(m, unsigned char *)+12),(rte_pktmbuf_mtod(m, unsigned char *)+16),m->pkt.data_len-16);
```

Packet dump after VLAN tag is removed:

```
0ca402e8 deb15254 00b3fb19 08004500 002a00fc 00003e11 bf42ac15 00000a5f 00aa0868 08680016 001c3202 1bdb0000 0000004e 00000e00
```

Can you please let me know how 0000 gets added in place of 0569 for source IP address in the modified packet after vlan tag is removed? 
What modification needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [rte_vlan_strip()](http://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__ether_8h.html#adaa89884932bf20e3ecc9c14b74cb305) DPDK function. Basically, it does what you need this way:

```
/* Copy ether header over rather than moving whole packet */
memmove(rte_pktmbuf_adj(m, sizeof(struct vlan_hdr)),
        eh, 2 * ETHER_ADDR_LEN);
```

In case you would need even faster solution, some NICs are able to strip VLAN tags for you. Have a look at [DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_VLAN_STRIP](http://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__ethdev_8h.html#a544a5d22a4be048e8e5395fb965922ed) flag which we can pass into [rte_eth_dev_configure()](http://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__ethdev_8h.html#a1a7d3a20b102fee222541fda50fd87bd) function.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.Will try and let you know.

Comment: This VLAN strip code works. The sourceIP address in the GTP Echo response is proper now  and is matching with the destination IP address received in the GTP Echo request.But I see another issue once the GTP Echo response goes past the host machine.The sourceIP address (172.21.240.231)in the GTP Echo response  is modified and is different from the source Ip address (172.21.5.105) seen in the tcpdump collected on the guest machine.Is this due to NAT functionality?Whether Virtual box translates the IP address and sends the packet as if originating from the host machine or is it because of DHCP?

Comment: By default VirtualBox uses NAT, but actually it depends on your configuration: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat

Comment: Unable to ping the IP 172.21.240.231 from the host machine nor from the guest.The ifconfig output and the netstat doesn't show this IP address. If NAT functionality is disabled is there any reason why KVM host (SRIOV) has to change the source IP address in the message received from the guest.How do I check for this IP address ?

Comment: The answer depends if your network interface is a PCI pass-through (SR-IOV) or an emulated device. But anyway it has nothing to do with the VLAN stripping, so please ask it as a separate question.

Comment: The network interface is a  PCI pass-through SR-IOV.